# How do I handle a situation where one of my players wants another player gone?

Tags: system-agnostic, problem-players, group-dynamics

I run a game with around 6 people. One of my players (A) wants another one of my players (B) not to play with us anymore.

A has come to me in the past two different times with complaints about B, saying that B's being really disruptive during the sessions (which he was) and that he was saying offensive things/putting offensive memes in the group chat. I talked to B about it and he said that he'd work on it. This was about a month or so ago.

Just now, A has texted me saying that B has now posted some white supremacist stuff in that group chat and that he doesn't feel safe playing with B anymore and that he thinks we should should stop playing with him.

Should I ask the other group members what they think (which would be completely biased, since two of the other members were B's friends before we started playing) or should I just ask B to leave?

Comment: I edited your question so that the title is phrased as a question. Please adjust it if you feel that I have changed the meaning in a way that you do not intend :)

Comment: Your question is a little confusing...  it sounds like you're just having to take A's word that B is posting stuff about white supremacy and other offensive things in the group chat, do you not have access to this chat?  Also, how the group is organized might be important - you mention not everyone was friends before the game, so is it a school club (if so, college, high school, other?) or were invites passed through friends-of-friends or what?  Different situations might call for different responses.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Can you get a proof of the things that happen in the group chat? Or do you have to take it on faith?

Comment: What is your relationship to these people? Why is it assumed that you have authority to oust someone?

Comment: Is this game run online or in-person?

Comment: I'm closing this question because in its current shape it is primarily inviting opinion. However given some additional information this could be potentially answerable. That information is: (a) What is your relationship to these individuals? Is this a random internet group or a number of close friends? (b) What's your visibility into this group chat? And most importantly for this not being primarily opinion-based: (c) What's your goal? What kind of resolution would you like? We can guide you concretely in how to achieve that goal, which would make this not primarily opinion-based.

Comment: This question is attracting a lot of unsubstantiated answers (prior to being put on hold). Please remember to cite your experience in this issue when you try to solve the querent's problem. Unsubstantiated answers that are insufficiently backed up by experience are impossible to validate for quality and will likely be down-voted and risk deletion for violating site policies.

Comment: @Rykara FYI it is not important for titles to be phrased as questions. They are just titles: their purpose is solely to act as an indicative summary of what the question is about. To this end they are often questions, but the original title was also fine.

Answer (score 16):

The purpose of a tabletop RPG is to be an interactive social experience where all parties involved can enjoy themselves. If at any point this is not happening then it has stopped being a fruitful and worthwhile experience.

In most situations where someones enjoyment was being infringed upon I would council weighing their concerns and discussing it with all parties involved in order to come to an amicable agreement that allowed everyone to continue enjoying themselves, or at least allowed the most people to continue doing so. However, this is not a normal situation. If player B has continued to post offensive content after being warned about it then that is already a repeat infraction.

If the offensive content is indeed white supremacist material then it bridges into something entirely different, no longer just a source of discomfort but indeed a source of real danger and dread for your other players. I do not know Player A's situation, whether they are a POC, a woman, a religious minority, lgbt, or if they are just a white straight Christian dude who is uncomfortable with bigotry, but the very nature of white supremacy is antithetical to the environment of TTRPG because it is inherently dangerous to everyone.

Of course ask to see the group chats and verify if what they say is going on, but also be prepared to act on it if and when it is true, and also if you feel it isn't white supremacist ask Player A to tell you why they think it is, and then address the situation with player B to see their response. Player B's reaction might tell you everything that you need, but don't ever tell them it was Player A that pointed it out, for their own safety.

Answer (score 13):

Ask to see the group chat posts before you make your decision. Evidence is hard to argue with, and seeing as you’ve had to talk to B before about offensive content, it would be harder for them to claim it’s a joke.

If A is correct and he is posting these sorts of things, it may be best to let B go. Otherwise, you are likely going to lose player A if they don’t feel safe playing at your table. Better to lose the troublemaker and avoid being tarred with the same brush as them.